# Font changes after reply in Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-10, fonts, microsoft-outlook-2010, size

I have a user that sends mails with default font Arial size 12 but when the mail is sent it changes automatically to Arial size 10.

So the user is typing with Arial 12 but when it's sent it's Arial 12.

TS Steps:

1. This happens with New mail/Reply/Reply all/Forward
2. Checked the Fonts and Stationary and it's on default
3. Checked the Format Text and made sure it's on default (HTML)
4. Windows has the latest update

Windows 7 SP1
Outlook 2010 Version: 14.0.7128.5000

Additional information:

I use Windows 10 system to test the email, it's normal. Does it bug for Windows 7?

Comment: (1) Is something set in *Options > Mail > Stationery and Fonts* ? (2) Are you on Apple (iOS)? (3) Is it a custom font?

Answer (score 1):

What you see is normal for older Outlook.

You are replying to an email sent to you.

The composer of the email used the 10 point font (or whatever setup they use).

The reply takes on the original characteristics of the received email.

You would need to change manually if you wish to change.

This is an Outlook characteristic and not related to the operating system.

Replies are different than new emails (which will be what you define).

Remember that you are using out of date / out of support Outlook.

I use modern Outlook myself.

Comment: Hi,  there are some mis understanding, I mean when I reply the same email, although my outlook setting reply font is 12, but when user got my reply email. It suddenly change font 10. (It's normal in win10 , user receieve mail font is 12)

Comment: It may depend on some setting in Outlook but overall, what you describe is a function of Outlook.